# ssrs row background color based on group total

Tags: reporting-services

What i have is a 3 group report, what I want to be able to do is if the sum of textbox145 (which is on group2) is >= make the entire background color DimGrey of group 2.  I know how to change the entire row color, however, I am unable to figure out how to do that total of that group based on the data of that groups sum

Thanks!

answered my own question...

=Iif(ReportItems!textbox145.Value >= 10,"DimGrey","Silver")

Answer (score 1):

The Sum function can use a scope argument, so set your background color to:

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!FieldNameforTB145.Value, "Group2Name") >= 100, "LightGrey", "Transparent")
```

The "Group2Name" in there is the magic bit that will give you what you want. This can be set to any parent group name that contains the current data element, but can't be set to a child group. (Which instance would the item use in that case?)